# Access token not defined

Tags: javascript, json, oauth-2.0, fetch, access-token

I get the following error in res.console : "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: access_token is not defined." Apparently the token is not picked up, possibly because it is not global: if so, how do I make it global here?

Here a screenshot of the code.
[screenshot console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5T3j.jpg)

I expect to be able to pick up and use the access token which was returned in a previous fetch in order to be able fetch other data.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Screenshot added now.

Comment: Update the `access_token` param at line 42 to `fetched_access_token` in line 41